# AWS DEVICE FARM - iOS - UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, aws-device-farm

When I run tests locally or on Circle CI they work 100% of the time. On AWS they fail 95% of the time with this error, not a test fail. I have tried manually and with fastlane, same result. I have also removed everything from the tests. If any piece of UI is interacted with it causes this failure. If test is empty it will succeed.  Anyone have a solution? Thanks

UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=9 "Error getting main window -25204" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error getting main window -25204}

Comment: I seemed to have solved this, by adding sleep(1) after app.launch(). It seems a little hacky, but has worked. The next issue is app.launchEnvoirnment["key"] = "value" is being ignored on AWS, but once again run fine on Circle CI and locally.

Comment: Could you post this issue in the [AWS Device Farm forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193) and provide a link to a Run that was impacted? The team can investigate further with this information.